# OAuth2 - Create Cllient to call API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, linkedin-api, omniauth

I'm currently tring to do some calls to Linkedin API (or other API of course).
I'm using OAuth2 and Linkedin strategy gems. The link `http://my_app/auth/linkedin` works, and I have registered in database the information of `access_token`.

Now I try to ask the LinkedinApi to get some informations. The Linkedin gem has lines linke this (`gems/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2-0.1.5/lib/omniauth/strategies/linkedin.rb`) :

```
access_token.get("/v1/people/~:(#{options.fields.join(',')})?format=json").parsed
```

with access_token defined by

```
def access_token
  ::OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, oauth2_access_token.token, {
    :mode => :query,
    :param_name => 'oauth2_access_token',
    :expires_in => oauth2_access_token.expires_in,
    :expires_at => oauth2_access_token.expires_at
  })
end
```

My question is : how to create a `client` object, and a `oauth2_access_token` ?

A client can be created with `OmniAuth::Strategy::Linkedin.new(nil).client`, but I'm not sure this is the right method.

There is a lot of functions in `OAuth` gems, and I'm lost ! How to create simple call to API ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OAuth, you *always* need a token (not just a client) to make authorized requests -- the token constitutes your authorization. The difference is whether you need authorization from a user or not. If you do, then you need to involve the user to get the token (using either the Authorization Code or Implicit Grant flows), and after you have the token you can use it to make authorized requests for protected resources that the user has granted you authorization for. If not, then you can get a token using only your application's credentials, using the Client Credentials OAuth flow. After that, you can use that token to access protected resources that your client has access to on its own. But either way, you need a token before you can make API requests.

But to get a Client Credentials token, OmniAuth is the wrong tool. Omniauth describes itself as ["a library that standardizes multi-provider authentication for web applications."](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) You're talking about making authorized requests for protected resources using [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). These things are not entirely unrelated, because most Omniauth strategies use OAuth2, since the [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) standard is built on top of OAuth2. But OAuth is an *authorization* protocol, not authentication. OmniAuth uses it, but it's not designed for making just any request for protected resources -- it's designed solely for authenticating your application's users.

What you want is the [OAuth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2). If you use OmniAuth, you've already got this gem -- it's a dependency. But it has the API you're looking for, not OmniAuth.